# How to create an empty space after last element in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView from support.v7 library to display items on shopping list.

When I'm scrolling to the end of my data, I can't see the price in the right side of the last item.

I want to add some space after scrolling to the last item, so that the button don't cover it.

Here is the image of the App with RecyclerView and FAB:

[image: App with RecyclerView and FAB]

I can simply add an empty object to the list for an Adapter, but in this case it will behave like the rest of rows (it will have checkbox, and price 00.00 on the right side).

Is there another way to do that?

Comment: try to add an empty item

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can add `bottomPadding` and disable `clipping`, such as:

```
<RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <!-- Bottom Padding, or space below last item -->
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"

    <!-- Clipping diabled -->
    android:clipToPadding="false" />
```